# Google Sheets Sorting resets my function values even though they are cached

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a pet project in google sheets that keeps track of the tv shows i've watched and syncs them up with the data in imdb (via some free api from [www.omdbapi.com](https://www.omdbapi.com)) to tell me what show I'm falling behind on, and should continue watching. I have a free account and I can only make 1k requests per day, so caching is an absolute MUST -- which is why there is caching EVERYWHERE. Issue I'm having is that `onEdit` runs, and sorts everything (expected), but re runs all the functions and I get these "Loading..." all over the place even though ALL of the functions are cached, I suspect google is making some of these fail?! But they don't "Error" (in the "Execution" tab) and they say "Completed" with no logs.

Does anyone know where the bottleneck is? And more importantly, how to fix it?

Here is the [read only link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a4l6clIazG9QUKD9XdMU2w7usk9pMMDQsOuKsGm9ur0/edit#gid=0) to try it out.

[image]

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

var APIKEY = 'xxxxxxx';
var CACHE_URL = 60 * 30; // 30 min
var CACHE_FUNCTION = 60 * 60 * 24; // 1 day

function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:K100");
  range.sort([
    {column: 9, ascending: false},  // continue watching
    {column: 10, ascending: false},  // my ratings
    {column: 8, ascending: true},  // days since
  ]);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}

function _cacheResult(key, callback, format, ttl) {
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var cached = cache.get(key);
  if (cached != null) {
    console.log(`found in cache: ${key}`, cached);
    return format(cached);
  }
  var data = callback();
  if (data == null) {
    console.log(`cannot cache: ${key}`);
    return data;
  }
  console.log(`cached!: ${key}`, data);
  cache.put(key, data, ttl);
  return format(data);
}

function _getJSON(url) {
  var key = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, url)  
                     .map(function(chr){return (chr+256).toString(16).slice(-2)})
                     .join('');
  var callback = function() {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
    var rawData = response.getContentText();
    console.log(response.getResponseCode(), rawData);
    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      return rawData;
    }
    return null;
  }
  return _cacheResult(key, callback, JSON.parse, CACHE_URL)
}

function getSeasonDetail(imdbId, season) {
  return _getJSON(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${imdbId}&apikey=${APIKEY}&season=${season}`);
}

function _getValidEpisode(episodes) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  console.log(episodes);
  for (var i = episodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (episodes[i]['Released'] == 'N/A') {
      console.log(`Skipping episode ${i+1}: unreleased`);
      continue;
    }
    var dateSince = (currentDate - (new Date(episodes[i]['Released'])));
    console.log(`Episode ${i+1}: ${dateSince}`);
    if (dateSince > 0) {
      console.log(`Episode ${i+1}: found!`);
      return episodes[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getIMDBRating(imdbId) {
  if (!imdbId) {
    return '';
  }
  var callback = function() {
    var data = _getJSON(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${imdbId}&apikey=${APIKEY}`);
    return data['imdbRating'];
  }
  return _cacheResult(`rating:${imdbId}`, callback, parseFloat, CACHE_FUNCTION);
}

function getCurrentSeason(imdbId) {
  if (!imdbId) {
    console.log(`Ignoring.. bad id`, imdbId);
    return '';
  }
  var callback = function() {
    var data = _getJSON(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${imdbId}&apikey=${APIKEY}`);
    var season = data['totalSeasons'];
    while (season) {
      var seasonDetail = getSeasonDetail(imdbId, season);
      var episode = _getValidEpisode(seasonDetail['Episodes']);
    
      if (episode === null) {
        console.log(`Season ${season} has no episodes ${imdbId}`);
        season -= 1;
        continue;
      }

      return season;
    }
  }
  return _cacheResult(`current_season:${imdbId}`, callback, parseInt, CACHE_FUNCTION);
}

function getCurrentSeasonEpisode(imdbId, season) {
  if (!imdbId) {
    console.log(`Ignoring.. bad id`, imdbId);
    return '';
  } else if (!season || isNaN(parseInt(season))) {
    console.log(`Ignoring ${imdbId}.. bad season id`, season);
    return '?';
  }
  var callback = function() {
    var data = getSeasonDetail(imdbId, season);  
    var episode = _getValidEpisode(data['Episodes']);
    if (episode === null) {
      console.log(`Ignoring.. bad episode response`, episode);
      return '?';
    }
    return episode['Episode'];
  }
  return _cacheResult(`current_episode:${imdbId}:${season}`, callback, parseInt, CACHE_FUNCTION);
}

function getCurrentSeasonEpisodeReleased(imdbId, season) {
  if (!imdbId) {
    console.log(`Ignoring.. bad id`, imdbId);
    return '';
  } else if (!season || isNaN(parseInt(season))) {
    console.log(`Ignoring ${imdbId}.. bad season id`, season);
    return '?';
  }
  var callback = function() {
    var data = getSeasonDetail(imdbId, season);
    var episode = _getValidEpisode(data['Episodes']);
    if (episode === null) {
      console.log(`Ignoring.. bad episode reponse`, episode);
      return '?';
    }
    return episode['Released'];
  }
  return _cacheResult(`current_episode_released:${imdbId}:${season}`, callback, String, CACHE_FUNCTION);
}
```

Comment: Your onEdit function runs on every user edit of every sheet in your spreadsheet.

Comment: By guessing your goal, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that in your situation when `onEdit` is run, the rows are sorted. By this, the cell coordinates used by the formulas are also changed. By this, the formulas are recalculated. I think that this might be the reason for your issue.

If you don't want to recalculate the formulas, how about the following workaround?

1. Fix the values from the formulas, that the HTTP request is run, to the values.
2. In this case, even when the rows are sorted, `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` is not run.
3. When you want to update the values, the fixed values are updated by putting the formulas in the cells.

With this workaround, I thought that the quotas of the API might be able to be reduced.

In order to use this workaround, please add the following 2 functions.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Spreadsheet.

```js
// Values of columns E,F,G and K are fixed.
function fixValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRangeList(["E3:G" + lastRow, "K3:K" + lastRow]).getRanges().forEach(r => r.copyTo(r, { contentsOnly: true }));
}

// In order to update values, formulas are put to columns E,F,G and K.
function updateValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var formulas = [
    "=getCurrentSeason(R[0]C[-4])", // To column E
    "=getCurrentSeasonEpisode(R[0]C[-5], R[0]C[-1])", // To column F
    "=getCurrentSeasonEpisodeReleased(R[0]C[-6], R[0]C[-2])", // To column G
    "=getIMDBRating(R[0]C[-10])", // To column K
  ];
  sheet.getRangeList(["E3:E" + lastRow, "F3:F" + lastRow, "G3:G" + lastRow, "K3:K" + lastRow]).getRanges().forEach((r, i) => r.setFormulaR1C1(formulas[i]));
}
```

- `fixValues()`: This function is used for fixing the values of columns E, F, G, and K.
- `updateValues()`: This function is used for updating the values of columns E, F, G, and K using the formulas.

#### Testing:

In order to test this script, please do the following flow.

1. Please run `fixValues()` to your provided sample Spreadsheet. By this, the cells which have the formulas are fixed as the values.
2. Please edit the cells. By this, the rows are sorted. In this case, the formulas are not recalculated because of no formulas.
3. Please run `updateValues()`. By this, the values are updated by putting the formulas to the columns E, F, G, and K.

I thought that by this flow, your issue might be removed.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Spreadsheet. So, when you change the structure of the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
- [setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformular1c1formula)